# Как включить видимость полного пути в vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Вот такая проблема, где можно изменить видимость и сделать полный путь к файлу? Видел что есть какая то настройка в vscode[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В настройках

<kbd>Функции</kbd> / <kbd>Проводник</kbd>

Галочка ***Compact Folders***.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `,` --> `Explorer: Compact Folders`